# Boot and install broken because of half-lib-c installation

Tags: boot, apt

I was trying to install wavemon and I ended up breaking up my apt-get by half installing some libc related packages.
My system doesn't boot to login screen anymore.

```
root@pc:~# apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.28-8 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.28-8 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.28) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
         Breaks: nscd (< 2.28)
         Recommends: libidn2-0 (>= 2.0.5~) but 2.0.4-1.1build2 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.28-8 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.28-8 is installed
 libcogl20 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not installed
 libegl-mesa0 : Depends: libgbm1 (= 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2) but it is not installed
 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not installed
 libmutter-2-0 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 17.1.0~rc2) but it is not installed
 libnl-genl-3-200 : Depends: libnl-3-200 (= 3.4.0-1) but 3.2.29-0ubuntu3 is installed
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not installed
 nscd : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.28-8 is installed
 xserver-xorg-core : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 10.2~0) but it is not installed
 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not installed
 xwayland : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 10.2~0) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@pc:~#
```

Edit 1 :

Boot screen :
[image: Boot log]

Comment: What distribution are you using? Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Yes 4.15.0-45-generic

Answer (score 1):

You need to downgrade `libc6` to the appropriate version for your distribution:

```
sudo apt install libc6=2.27-3ubuntu1
```

This will probably fail because of other broken dependencies, you’ll need to remove or downgrade those too.

Wavemon is available in Ubuntu 18.04, you could install that version (0.8.1):

```
sudo apt install wavemon/bionic
```

This will avoid pulling in a version of `libc6` which is inappropriate for your system.

Comment: I'll try right away. I added a screen of my boot log as well

Comment: When downgrading, I would always re-run at the end a second time the command for all downgraded packages with --reinstall: avoids corner cases where a file can get lost during downgrade (related to the way "Replaces: " works during upgrade)

Comment: i fixed it by downgrading manually wget then dpkg -i
I then had a problem with cloud-init, i fixed it using https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1513609/comments/1